# Issue with saving xls files that located on SharePoint 2013 on-premises

Tags: sharepoint-server, office

2 WFE - Load balancing  by NetScaler /
2 APP - Load balancing  by NetScaler

Office 2010 on client machines.

I have document library with xlsx files.
I click on the file in document library and open this file in edit mode on local computer. When i try to save, i very often receive conflict saving error. But nobody works with this file at the moment. Only i know where this file is located and only i have access to this library.

Sometimes file saving without any issues.

Many users in our company faced this problem.

I checked event viewers and SharePoint logs on servers but didn't found any related entries.

[image]

Comment: It occurs only when i visit SharePoint via load balancer.  If i visit  SharePoint by direct link to one of 2 wfe servers name - file saving  works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing latest CU and restart servers problem is gone.